# jQuery can't find &lt;

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

I have a web page containing a dropdown (select) with some options. Due to some reasons I need to set the value of these options with a string like below (that contains < and >)

```
<select id="m" name="m" >
 <option value="" selected="selected" >All</option>
 <option value=" x&lt;10 ">MyOption</option>    
</select>
```

And then I need to select the eight (intended) option using jquery as follows:

```
$('#m').val(' x&lt;10 ');
```

But it doesn't work despite the parameter string is exactly same as the value of the option.
I tested several times with different characters, and they all worked but the string containing `&lt; and &gt;` are not recognized. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `&lt;` is converted to `<` when the HTML is read by the browser. The result is that the option's value is `x<10` (with a space on either side).

So `$('#m').val(' x<10 ')` should work. Alternatively,
`document.getElementById('m').selectedIndex = 1` would too